# Filter 2 columns by current date sql

Tags: sql

Not sure this question has been asked before though.

I am trying to filter out 2 columns(datPromisedDelivery,datCommisioned) by the current date.

The data should be shown which have dates within yesterday and tomorrow(-1,+1)

It is a quite a long query which I've written.

```
SELECT
    nJobNumber,
    strClientName,
    strClientReference,
    strJobCategory,
    datCommisioned,
    datPromisedDelivery 
FROM vwJobBookForXML  
where bCompleted=0 and  
    nJobNumber is not null and  
    strClientReference is not null and  
    datPromisedDelivery BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) and  DATEADD(DAY, +1, GETDATE()) and  
    datCommisioned BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) and  DATEADD(DAY, +1, GETDATE())  
ORDER BY nJobNumber;
```

Probably the query contains some syntax errors since the program outputs an empty CSV file.

Can anyone guess what's wrong with the query, please?

Comment: The first question you should ask - are there any rows with given dates?

Comment: You're tagged as mysql, but that doesn't look like mysql date_add syntax.

Comment: Or more precisely, are there any rows where *both* dates are in range? Also, which database are you using? MySQL or SQL Server? They are quite different.

Comment: Oh shit! Why didn't I notice it? You're a real legend. There's nothing wrong with my query. It's working. Thanks, heaps! @jirigracik

Comment: Don't worry, it happens all the time. You will eventually get used to it @RyanOscar

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language (and your query is non standard SQL), not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0):

DATEADD is a SQL server function.

Use DATE_ADD if it's MYSQL:

```
fieldName BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

You should check your error handling/logging if your only indicator of an SQL error is an empty file.